# How to maximize browser in minitest-rails selenium test?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, minitest

I'm doing **minitest-rails** with **feature** testing.

I noticed that the browser (i'm using chrome) is **NOT in full width**.

Where or how can I set it in my configuration file?

Currently I have installed the following **gems**:

```
  selenium-webdriver (2.53.4)
  chromedriver-helper (1.0.0)
  capybara (2.8.1, 2.7.1)
  capybara-screenshot (1.0.13)
  minitest-capybara (0.8.2)
  minitest-rails-capybara (2.1.2)
```

Please help!

Answer (score 6):

**SOLVED !!!**

Finally I found the solution:

There are **two(2)** options setting the browser's width and height.

**1st**: **Set the specific size**, ex:

> page.driver.browser.manage.window.resize_to(1366,768)

**2nd**: **Make it full size or maximize it**, ex:

> page.driver.browser.manage.window.maximize

Hope this help others :)

Comment: Thank the gods for creating you!  I will never get that day of my life back, but I won't have to spend another one fighting stupidly tiny selenium browser windows! ;)

Comment: It took me so long to find an answer that actually helped.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This also worked for me and is set once in the `ApplicationTestCase` class.

```
class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  Capybara.register_driver :selenium_remote_chrome do |app|
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
      app,
      browser: :remote,
      url: CHROMEDRIVER_URL,
      desired_capabilities: :chrome,
      options: options
    )
  end
end
```